# Install angular-cli for angular 2 project

Tags: linux, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to install Angular-CLI to generate an angular2 project, but it seems that the cli generate an angular 4 project. how can I fix that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344600/installing-a-specific-version-of-angular-with-angular-cli install whatever comes and change version in `package.json` and `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So jus to to save you some confusion, the latest version of Angular is 4.2.3, and I believe the CLI is at 1.1.2. The CLI will always configure your generate project to the the latest version of Angular (for the CLI).

Regardless of that, you shouldn't really stick on trying to create "Angular 2" applications. As a community the version number doesn't matter as much anymore. It's not like the migration from AngularJS (version 1) to Angular version 2. Angular version 4 is backwards compatible with Angular version 2. We aren't that concerned with version numbers. Anything and everything you do and how you do it in Angular version 2 will work as expected in the Angular version 4!

However by using the latest version you get new features (like the [if/else directives](https://medium.com/aviabird/ngif-else-lands-in-angular-2-0-a242940e54ff)).

Anyway, don't worry to much about the version number, you're just making Angular apps.