# Downgrade Angular version / not cli

Tags: angular, npm

I want to downgrade the Angular version of a specific project from 11 to 10.2.3 I have done the following:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install  @angular/cli@10.2.3
```

This as I see affects only the CLI version and not the Angular version. All the info I found was about this. I can nowhere find how to change the Angular version itself! Any suggestions?

Comment: What else do you expect it to change? `project.json`? You'll need to update that manually.

Comment: I think your solution can be found here [How to install Angular CLI locally (without the -g flag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128847/how-to-install-angular-cli-locally-without-the-g-flag)

Comment: @Cerbrus how do I know which of key-values am I going to change into package.json?

Comment: Find & replace the old version number.

Comment: I manually changed them to 10.2.3 but still the Angular version when i do ng --version remains 11