# How to create angular 6 project from angular cli 7.3.3

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

I have latest angular cli with version 7.7.3. I need angular 6 project using it. But I can able to create only angular 7 project from it using cli command  ng new project_name. Is there any way to force create angular 6 project? Node version : 10.2.1.
From git we can get seed but is it possible from latest cli?

Comment: please share the error log what error you are getting

Comment: Not about error. I want to know whether it is possible?

Comment: Question heading updated please note

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344600/installing-a-specific-version-of-angular-with-angular-cli

Comment: okay got your question added answer please check thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be too uninstall angular/cli globally

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

then reinstall it globally at the version you want so..

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.0`
```

then in your terminal create a new angular project like so

```
ng new <project-name>
```

at that point it will build you an angular 6 app, from there you can now safely uninstall the `@angular/cli` globally and reinstall the latest version like so

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Can I keep the cli version as 6. Without uninstall and install again? Why need to install again?

Comment: I saw one more like this ng new project_name --ng6

Comment: Yes you can keep the cli version at 6, I wasn’t sure if you wanted to stay at 7 or not.

Answer (score 3):

The following steps helped me to create angular 6 project from angular cli 7.3.3

Step 1 
      Create a new folder => mkdir angular6-project

Step 2
      Go to that folder => cd angular6-project

Step 3
      Check version => ng version
      so version is > Angular cli: 7.3.3

Step 4
      that folder open cmd >
      npm init -y

Step 5 
      install  angular cli 6 locally using >
      npm install @angular/cli@6

Step 6
     check ng version
     it's version is > Angular 6.1

Step 7
       You delete local pakcage.json file. Angular cli will complain when you try use ng 
        new

Step 8 
      You can create Angular 6 application >
      ng new ng6-app

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create the older version of the angular project using the newer version of angular-cli.

To solve your issue you need to downgrade the **angular-cli version 7.7.3 to 6.0.0** using below commands

**Step 1:** Uninstall current angular-cli 7.7.3 using below command

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

**Step 2:** Install angular-cli 6.0.0 using below command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.0
```

**Step 3:** Create Angular 6 Project using below command

```
ng new PROJECT-NAME
cd PROJECT-NAME
ng serve
```

**Step 4:** Now your project has its own local angular-cli installed,so you can now update your angular-cli version to 7.7.3 using below command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Hope this help!