# How to Create a Angular 8 application with Angular CLI 10 installed

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and following a tutorial of Angular 8 With Dot NET Core Web API.
Now When i created my new angular project by running ng new app then it creates a project of angular 10 i think. The package json file look like this https://ibb.co/pQvfX79
So my question is can i create a angular 8 application with angular CLI 10 because it what i need for my new project and if no then are angular versions dependent with angular CLI ?

Comment: You should be able to create a angular 10 project and then change the package versions to an angular 8 version.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a angular 10 project and then change the package versions to an angular 8 version. Afterwards `npm install` will install the provided versions for you.

This may also help: [Installing a specific version of angular with angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344600/installing-a-specific-version-of-angular-with-angular-cli)