# Angular cli installation command difference

Tags: angular

difference between these commands

npm install -g angular-cli

npm install -g angular/cli

was trying to install angularcli  using first command but it didn't get installed was getting error- AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed

but when I tried the second command angular cli got installed.

Is there any difference between two commands

Answer (score 2):

You get an error when using the first command `npm install -g angular-cli` because no such package exists with that name in the `npm repository`.

`@angular/cli` is the official package for installing CLI tool in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your're meaning `npm install`, not `ng install` ?

This difference is that the package name is `@angular/cli`. If you use another name, then you install another package (or nothing, if the name you provide is not taken).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

Comment: Yes I meant , npm install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344600/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-angular-with-angular-cli here in the second answer it is mentioned to use these command                                                                                                                        
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.32

Comment: npm install -g angular-cli why there was no error that package didn't exist . if we use command with invalid package name does it install all the packages mentioned in the package.json?

Comment: Yeah version 1. Angular is at version 17, which is 7 years later ... So just read the documentation next time.